# Find empirical formula when individual masses are known

Tags: molecules

I'd like to illustrate my question with an example:

Imagine nickel reacts with fluoride and you start with $0.766\ \mathrm{g}$ of nickel, an unknown amount of fluoride and you end with $1.261\ \mathrm{g}$ of nickel fluoride. The mass of fluoride in the end must then be $1.261\ \mathrm{g} - 0.766\ \mathrm{g} = 0.495\ \mathrm{g}$.

So, in the end, there are $0.013$ moles of nickel and $0.026$ moles of fluoride. Now the question is, what is the empirical formula for nickel fluoride? ($\small\ce{NiF2}$). I see that for every mole of nickel, you need $2$ moles of fluoride. Then why is the empirical formula $\small\ce{Ni2F4}$ incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An **empirical formula** is, according to [IUPAC’s *Gold Book* definition](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02063.html):

> Formed by juxtaposition of the atomic symbols with their appropriate subscripts to give the **simplest possible formula expressing the composition** of a compound

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_formula) goes even further:

> the simplest positive integer ratio of atoms of each element present in a compound

and then

> An empirical formula makes no reference to isomerism, structure, or **absolute number of atoms**.

So, NiF<sub>2</sub> is an empirical formula, while Ni<sub>2</sub>F<sub>4</sub> simply isn't. Another example is given by, again, Wikipedia:

> For example, formaldehyde, acetic acid and glucose have the same empirical formula, CH<sub>2</sub>O

Their molecular formulas (which account for the absolute number of atoms in a molecule) differ, though: formaldehyde CH<sub>2</sub>O, acetic acid C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>4</sub>O<sub>2</sub>, glucose C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>.

Comment: And what about H2O2?

Comment: H2O2 is a valid molecular formula, but not an empirical formula. The empirical formula is HO.